# AlertDialog - How I can make OutlinedTextFields prepopulated when user opens the AlertDialog?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog, android-navigation

I'm working on a mobile app where users can create reports by entering basic information and specifying a location on Google Maps. Users open AlertDialog by clicking on the FAB. After users enter the required data (title, desc, category, severity), the last step is to click a button that takes them to a new screen displaying Google Maps. On this screen, users can place a draggable pin anywhere on the map. When users click the "Save" button, I want to redirect them to the previous screen. AlertDialog should be open and the basic information they entered earlier should still be there, along with the latitude and longitude values in the background.

How can I achieve this functionality?

I am using Kotlin/Jetpack Compose, Nodejs and Postgres.

Comment: we can't help you if you don't provide a code to what you are talking about so we can know how your code is structured and stuff. please provide a basic code just for the part you need help with no need for all the project

Comment: `BottomSheet` widget would be better to suit for this functionality.